# Obtaining addresses using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, openstreetmap, address, europe

I am currently working on Eastern-European [microdistricts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdistrict), and I want to obtain the addresses that can be found in these microdistricts.

Is it possible to use ArcGIS to solve this issue? I thought about using an OSM Basemap and draw polygons where these microdistricts locate, and after that I can extract the addresses from it, but I am not so familiar in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the boundaries of the districts in question, you can draw a polygon and do a select by location where the points are completely within the newly drawn polygon. You can then export that data to a new file.

Comment: I drew the polygons, it is okay. But the problem is that I don't have a shapefile which consists the addresses, and I cannot choose the OSM Layer as a source layer when I perform the 'Select by location' operation